# Why does the HTML noresize attribute not work? Frames with this attribute still get resized with browser window. What does this attribute really do?

Tags: html, frames

I came accross this attribute for frames in HTML:noresize, which is meant to make the frame size fixed. However, despite using this attribute as under, the frame size changes on changing  width of browser. What is this attribute used for. Does it work with frames only or also with iframes.

```
  <frameset cols="*,*,*">
    <frame
      src="bianca.html"
      longdesc="https://www.google.com"
      noresize="noresize" style="height: 800px; width:400px"
>
    <frame src="second.html" >
      <frame src="second.html">
  </frameset>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frame#attr-noresize

Comment: It means that the user can't resize the frame dragging it, but if the frame has a percentage dimension is normal that the width change resizing the browser dimension

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-frame-noresize-attribute/
It can't be resized by the user.

Comment: Note that this element has been marked obsolete for at least 15 years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`noresize` tells the browser not to provide a user interface to resize frames. By default, you can point the mouse at a frame boundary, hold the button down and drag it.

`style="height: 800px; width:400px"` has no effect on a frame. The initial size of a frame is determined by the `cols` attribute. You said the size of the frame was `*` so it takes up a third of the available space.